# Where is the django CMS history tab?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

While editing pages in django CMS there is no history tab in the toolbar. Even on the django CMS official demo page there is no history tab in the toolbar. If this feature needs to be activated with some special setting, that setting is not in any documentation I could find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **History** entry on the toolbar was removed as of django CMS 3.4.

This was because the revisions (history) implementation had a lot of shortcomings.

As an initial replacement, we're releasing a new app which allows users to undo/redo plugin operations and in the future we will extend this app to support revisions (restore).

Last, the **Revert to live** entry will come back in django CMS 3.4.2

*Edit*

Here's the [djangocms-history](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-history) app.

Comment: Thank you! I think there should be a word or two about this in the official documentation beyond just a release note "Removed revision support from django CMS core".

Comment: Hi @Paulo, what's the name of the app you mentioned that allows undo/redo operations? Is it available now?

Comment: Hello @AndyF, I've updated my answer to include a link to the now public repo. The app is currently on beta and will be released on PyPI today or sometime this week.